# How to use 'id' when using DocumentDB via MongDB API in Spring DATA?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, azure-cosmosdb

I have used both the ways of mapping `_id` as described in the [Spring Docs here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.id-handling).

- using `@Id` annotation
- having a field with name `id` without any annotation

in my previous project where we used MongoDB as database and Spring Data for DAO operations. It worked without any problem for both `String` a well as for `BigInteger`.

Now we are [using DocumentDB with MongoDB API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-create-mongodb-account)(as Spring Data does not support DocumentDB).
I am able to use all the Spring Data methods, but I am not able to use custom id.

Below is my entity:

```
public class S{

    private String id;

    /* other fields here */

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /* getters and setters for other fields */
}
```

This is the DAO:

```
public interface SDao extends MongoRepository<S, String> {

}
```

Now if anywhere in my code I do:

```
s = new S();
s.setId("some-id-here");
```

The record gets successfully persisted in the DB with custom id `some-id-here` as `String` (not `ObjectId`), but after that it throws `ClassCastException` saying `Long` cannot be converted to `Integer`.

Same is the case when using `BigInteger` for id.

If I am not setting the custom id, i.e. I comment the setting of `id` as below:

```
s = new S();
// s.setId("some-id-here");
```

no exception is being thrown, but the record is being persisted with a random id provided by database itself as `ObjectcId`.

I want to save the record with custom id, so that I can easily update it when needed.
Currently if I have to update a record, I need to retrieve it using a key which is not mapped to `_id` and then update it and then delete the old record from the DB and then persist the updated one, which I feel is absolutely inefficient as I am not able to make use of `_id`.

My question is why am I getting `ClassCastException`, that too mentioning Conversion of **`Long` to `Integer`**

Is DocumentDB internally doing some conversion which is throwing this exception. If yes, how to tackle it? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative could be to let `DocumentDB/ MongoDB` create those `IDs` for you by default. In your class you can have another field which can serve as natural ID and create a unique index on that field for fetch optimization.
Refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/ for indexes.

Comment: Well, letting the default `id` being created by `mongoDB`/`DocumentDB` present in class and using our own natural id for operations works. Though there is one extra field now, but still it's affordable as compared to the workaround that we had to do for our update operations earlier. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The id generation rules are explained here [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.id-handling)

Comment: yeah, while following the rules to create custom id, I am getting exception (although record is being persisted).

Comment: You are probably looking for this solution posted on SO 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530485/spring-data-mongodb-biginteger-to-objectid-conversion

Comment: I remember not creating any custom converters when using MongoDB as the direct data store.